# Trigger rebuild manually on searchDelegate

Tags: android, flutter

I'm building a Flutter application and have a `SearchDelegate` function where I'm trying to put filters as a complement to the query. To do so, I have a `buildActions` button that displays the list of filters, you can choose what you want, and then the popup disappears and returns the list of filters.
I'm trying to force a reload of the search :

```
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    cubit.clearSearchResults();
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(
          ThemeIcon.clear,
        ),
        onPressed: query.isEmpty ? null : () => query = '',
      ),
      query.isNotEmpty
          ? IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(
          ThemeIcon.filter_list,
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          Map<String, dynamic>? selectedValues =
          await showDialog<Map<String, dynamic>>(
            barrierDismissible: true,
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return FiltersPopup(filters);
            },
          );
          if (selectedValues != null) {
            filters = selectedValues["filters"];
            // TODO : trigger rebuild
          }
        },
      )
          : const SizedBox.shrink(),
    ];
  }
```

I've tried :

- to change the query to force a reload but it's not working, the query is erased from the search bar but nothing happens after
- launch the function `buildResults` but without any success

Any help will be very appreciated :)